# Accessing json data in javascript strange error

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am returning json string from web service and I can easily access it but sometime it behave strange and I can not find why. 
 Here is json string that I am getting through web service

```
{"current":"2014-10-07T17:53:03+02:00","T1":{"0":[null],"1":[null],"2":[null],"3":[null],"4":[null],"5":[null],"6":[{"name":"ABC","value":63}]},"T2":{"0":[null],"1":[null],"2":[null],"3":[null],"4":[null],"5":[null]},"T3":{"0":[null],"1":[null],"2":[null],"3":[null],"4":[null],"5":[null]},"T4":{"0":[null],"1":[null],"2":[null],"3":[null],"4":[null],"5":[null]},"T5":{"0":[null],"1":[null],"2":[null],"3":[null],"4":[null],"5":[null]}}
```

I can access them easily and it is working fine except when there is null on 0th position of any T1,T2,T3...etc. It return this error `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

This is how I am accessing data

```
    if(json.T1 != undefined) {
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if(json.T1[i][0] == null) {
                t1.push(NaN)
            }
            else
            {
                t1.push(json.T1[i][0]["value"])
            }
        }
     }
```

I dont understand why this works in all the cases excpet having null of 0th position of T1, T2...etc

Comment: The error means that you are trying to access a property that doesn't exist, i.e. `json.T1[i]` returns `undefined`. What is the value of `len`? If it's larger than 6, then that's why you get the error. `json.T1[7]` doesn't exist in your example.

Comment: Why don't you test for `undefined` here? `json.T1[i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the len property doesn't represent the right length of the items that are into the T1 object.
Try to get the length by enumerating the T1 object properties.

```
var len = 0;
for(var item in json.T1){
   len++;
}
```

And then, try the script you provided. This should work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change some things.
Try this way: http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/jww96u92/

```js
var k = {
  "current": "2014-10-07T17:53:03+02:00",
  "T1": {
    "0": [null],
    "1": [null],
    "2": [null],
    "3": [null],
    "4": [null],
    "5": [null],
    "6": [{
      "name": "ABC",
      "value": 63
    }]
  },
  "T2": {
    "0": [null],
    "1": [null],
    "2": [null],
    "3": [null],
    "4": [null],
    "5": [null]
  },
  "T3": {
    "0": [null],
    "1": [null],
    "2": [null],
    "3": [null],
    "4": [null],
    "5": [null]
  },
  "T4": {
    "0": [null],
    "1": [null],
    "2": [null],
    "3": [null],
    "4": [null],
    "5": [null]
  },
  "T5": {
    "0": [null],
    "1": [null],
    "2": [null],
    "3": [null],
    "4": [null],
    "5": [null]
  }
};
var t1 = [];
console.log(k);
if (k.T1 != undefined) {
  $.each(k.T1, function(i, item) {
    if (item[0] == null) {
      t1.push(NaN)
    } else {
      alert("I just put " + item[0]["value"] + "in t1 array!Thanks!");
      t1.push(item[0]["value"])
    }
    console.log(item);
  });
  console.log(t1);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The OP never mentioned jQuery anymore. Also, what did you change? What was the problem? Just posting code and saying "try this" is not really helpful.

Comment: The code is showing above is not full.What is json val there?where is the initialization ?what is len? So i tried with the same logic but with other way to access [0] element (if you see in code) and no error caused.I think is a solution.If i had all the code ,i would exmplain more his/her error.

Comment: But in some way myabe you have right i gave a working solution to the logic of this case but I didn't answer the queston about the error itself.I am more practical. :)